# Program to automatically switch between programs in Windows

Tags: windows-xp

I already did some googling, but did not find anything. I need a program, which cycles automatically between a number of applications currently openend in my Windows XP. I use it for an external Infoscreen (2nd screen) and I keep on working on the 1st one. That's why I can not use 
http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/AutoTab.shtml
because it switches between ALL open programs.
I want to set the programs to cycle through.

Thx,
Martin

Comment: doesn't sound like a programming question. I think you should post this question on superuser.com

Answer (score -1):

You could use [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), or more simply, write a vbscript and specify the applications that you want to switch. See [here](https://superuser.com/a/699859) for an example.